# How can I redirect after delay() with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery `delay()` function to delay a `show()` event, but after that I want to change the location.href of the page. How can I do that?

```
$('#error').delay(800).show();
location.href = '/profile'
```

Sorry, I forgot to mention I want to delay the redirect as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provide a callback for show()

```
$('#error').delay(800).show(0, function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = '/profile'
    }, 8000);
});
```

documentation on .show() http://api.jquery.com/show/

The 'show' will happen after 800 milliseconds, then after the element is shown, the redirect will occur 8 seconds later. With this code you will have 2 'delays' so to speak.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I want to delay the redirect as well.

Comment: Just add a setTimeout for the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.setTimeout()` instead, `.delay` could only be used to jQuery animation.

```
$('#error').show();
setTimeout(function() {
  location.href = '/profile';
}, 800);
```

Comment: This isn't the correct way to go when using jQuery. Callbacks are there for a reason. Obviously your code works fine, but if the OP wanted to complicate this in any way by adding more chained calls, then you'd want to use callbacks.